# How to access datatable from admin namespace to public in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two namespaces in my project they are Admin and FrontEnd. I want to show a datatable in frontend home page, so I need to access same model from the admin namespace.. When I call the model in front end its showing an authentication error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it my self. I create separate datatable and route for that home page.